# How to add items in Laravel session array

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm using Laravel 4.2. I have a method for storing files and  I'm trying to push items in session array. Every time user clicks on a button, I want to save these file names in session array with a name and later I should get them.

I'm trying with the following code:

```html
$name = Input::get('name');
$input = Input::all();
foreach ($input[$name] as $key => $corporate) {

  $file_name = $key.'_'.$current_time . '_' . $corporate->getClientOriginalName();
  //code for uploading files
  if(Session::has($name)) {
     Session::push($name.".".$key, $file_name); //I want to add new items in this array
  } else {
    Session::put($name, $file_name); //for first image
  }


}
```

As I read from laravel docs:

> Push A Value Onto An Array Session Value
>
> Session::push('user.teams', 'developers');

);`

But it doesn't add new items to array, it overwrites it.

After first image upload in session array I have:

```html
["director_front_passport[]"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(54) "0_1472669237_12894473_678457885627912_1258115018_o.jpg"
    }
  }
```

After uploading second image, session is:

```html
["director_front_passport[]"]=>
  array(1) {
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(33) "0_1472669255_animated_loading.gif"
    }
  }
```

What is the proper way to push items in session array with definite name, I mean I should get these items later using: Session::get('name') for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
$name = Input::get('name');
$input = Input::all();
$items = Session::get($name, []);
foreach ($input[$name] as $key => $corporate) {
  $file_name = $key.'_'.$current_time . '_' . $corporate->getClientOriginalName();
  if (!array_key_exists($key, $items)) {
      $items[$key] = [];
  }
  $items[$key][] = $file_name;
}
Session::put($name, $items);
```

Comment: I use this method when I should add new item to existing session array. That's why I need this check if I have a session - if(Session::has($name)) {
     Session::push($name.".".$key, $file_name);
  } else {
    Session::put($name, $file_name);

Comment: But if you're storing multiple items at the same Session key, it makes more sense to store an array of items. Having one item each at a number of similar addresses ('name', 'name0', 'name1', etc) isn't as clean as having `Session::get('name') = [item0, item1, item2, ...]`

Comment: My code will push the item if it doesn't exist after the loop. I cannot check on my local machine. But it would be helpful if you print the result and tell what is wrong.